# Protect all folder and a file contents, but gain access to website wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, security, password-protection

Googled shows password protect via .htaccess file wp-admin, wp-includes,wp-config folders n file resp. or use host server option of protecting directories.This locks webpages asking password. to a visitor.
I Need to lock on server side and displaying web pages.
So on Cpanel wp-admin folder to be locked on server side and www.example.com/wp-admin.php through link but website www.example.com & pages www.example.com/watches www.example.com/walls...etc should be displayed
.htaccess file and uploading it in /wp-admin/ directory locks website pages too following codes in there:

```
AuthName "Admins Only"
AuthUserFile /home/yourdirectory/.htpasswds/public_html/wp-admin/passwd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType basic
require user putyourusernamehere
```

Comment: If you want people to see your website you have to let them access it

Comment: @RiggsFolly sir with all respect can you reply to my query

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to do what I think you may be asking

Comment: any clue or my Question is incorrect